# How to replace a part of a string to a different character in XSL

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, workday-api

I'm new to XSLT and coding in general.
However, I have to fix my codes so I can provide the correct output.

Basically, some strings/values that I'm trying to produce in XSL contains a comma "," but I can't have that because my output file is going to be CSV. so with the commas, it's going to mess up my output file. So I need to replace the commas in the string/values to an apostrophe "'".

Example of my lines below:

<xsl:value-of select="replace(wd:HomeAddress/@wd:Descriptor),'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',''"/>

just got the above from random searches in google before I finally ended up here.

Comment: I don't thinks this is the right approach. You can either use a different delimiter for csv file  or enclose text values into double quotes or both.

Comment: You can use the `translate()` function to replace one character with another. But I agree with Vasya: the CSV format allows in-field commas, provided the field is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: P.S. Your chances of assembling a working XSLT solution from snippets of code found online are practically nil.

Comment: @michael.hor257k , my original code was "wd:HomeAddress/@wd:Descriptor" which already has double quotes and is producing an output. but the commas are splitting up my fields and messing up the entire file. any tips? or am I missing something on the double quotes?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot answer without seeing the entire picture - see: [mcve]. It is also possible that the target application does not know how to parse a CSV file properly; in such case, you have no choice but to mangle the data. However, the CSV format is old and well-known, so that's not very likely.

Comment: What XSL processor are you using? Do you have to use a specific one? Could you write a program (like in Python or Go) to decode the XML then properly encode CSV? And, like @michael.hor257k, said, we need to see some example of the input to know how to help. Good luck :)

Answer (score -2):

Use translate :

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(wd:HomeAddress/@wd:Descriptor,',','''')"/>
```

This is simple function to change characters by others

EDIT: corrected the delimiters .

Comment: 1. Your code will produce an error. 2. Your code attempts to remove the character, not replace it with another.

Comment: The I forgot to put the ' character inside the 3rd parameter.

Comment: It will still produce an error because the function's name  is `translate` not `Translate`. And you also forgot to mention that your syntax requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : corrected . But translate is indeed XSLT 1.0. Not use very often but can be useful in this kind of situation

Comment: `translate()` is indeed XSLT 1.0 - but your syntax of escaping an apostrophe by doubling it will produce an error when used with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: I would like to thank you all! the code given by Ptit Xav works now.